# How do I add linker commands to Microsoft Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, visual-studio-2019

I am writing a short program that uses the MPIR (Multiple Precision Integers and Rationals) library. In the manual it states that your program must link against the following library, and that the command would look something like this on a typical Unix system:

```
g++ mycxxprog.cc -lmpirxx -lmpir
```

How do I do this for Microsoft Visual Studio 2019? Is there something simple in the Linker project settings where I can just add a command like this? Sorry if this has been asked before, but it's just too technical for me to understand at this point, and I'm just trying to do some homework. I also can't find any tutorials explaining this.

Comment: Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you could follow the following steps:

1,Add the path to the header file to the Additional Include Directories(property - >c/c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories)

2,Add the path to the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories (property -> linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories)

3,Add the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies (property -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies)

For more details I suggest you could refer to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019#UseLibInApp

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! You are a life saver!!!!!!!!!!!! My program even ran on the first compile! :)))))

Comment: @Azi muth We are appreciate that you are satisfied with the help we provide. If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers.

Comment: Ah sorry I see the solved button now. Solved!